# How to write procedure with several output parameters?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created this procedure but this is throwing error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSurrenderPolicyDetails
  @policy_Id int,
  @name nvarchar(50) output,
  @policy_Amount Decimal(10,2) output,
  @premiumPaidTillDate Decimal(10,2) output
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT 
      @name = Policy_Details.Name,
      @policy_Amount = Insurance_Policy_Details.Policy_Amount,
      @premiumPaidTillDate = SUM(Payment_Premium_Details.Premium_Amount)
  FROM
      Policy_Details  
  INNER JOIN 
      Payment_Premium_Details ON (Policy_Details.Policy_Id = Payment_Premium_Details.Policy_Id)  
  INNER JOIN 
      Insurance_Policy_Details ON (Policy_Details.Ins_Id = Insurance_Policy_Details.Ins_Id)
  WHERE
      Policy_Details.Policy_Id = @policy_Id;      
END
GO
```

The error says

> Column 'Policy_Details.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error ? We cannot see your screen, nor can we read your mind - you'll have to **tell us** exactly what that error is!

Comment: One thing that's pretty obvious: there's no **join condition** on your first `INNER JOIN` - **what** column(s) do you want to join that table on???

Comment: After making the changes it is still giving me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error is pretty clear: you have a `SUM()` aggregate in your `SELECT`, so therefore, you need to use `GROUP BY` for the other columns in your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT 
      @name = Policy_Details.Name,
      @policy_Amount = Insurance_Policy_Details.Policy_Amount,
      @premiumPaidTillDate = SUM(Payment_Premium_Details.Premium_Amount)
FROM
      Policy_Details  
INNER JOIN 
      Payment_Premium_Details ON (Policy_Details.Policy_Id = Payment_Premium_Details.Policy_Id)  
INNER JOIN 
      Insurance_Policy_Details ON (Policy_Details.Ins_Id = Insurance_Policy_Details.Ins_Id)
WHERE
      Policy_Details.Policy_Id = @policy_Id;      
GROUP BY
      Policy_Details.Name,
      Insurance_Policy_Details.Policy_Amount,
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem isn't your output parameters, but your join clauses; Instead, try something like:

```
INNER JOIN  Insurance_Policy_Details 
    ON      Policy_Details.Ins_Id = Insurance_Policy_Amount.Ins_Id

INNER JOIN  Payment_Premium_Details 
    ON      Policy_Details.Policy_Id = Payment_Premium_Details.Policy_Id
```